# How to make a web based file uploader which monitors a local folder

Tags: html, file-upload, synchronization, local-files

I have a java swing based UI which I use to monitor a filesystem folder. Anytime a new file is added to the folder, i upload it onto my web server.

I'd like to drop the java interface and go for a web app with a simple file uploader UI where the user can see the files being upoaded and which were uploaded.

The workflow;
User open browser. Opens the web app page. Browses and selects the local filesystem folder which needs to be monitored. Over the hours as the new files are added to the local folder, they are shown in the web interface and get uploaded onto the server.

My question is what all technologies can i use to implement this. I already have the HTMl based web Ui ready. I now need to monitor(/sync?) a selected local folder. what all do i need to do that. I remember there was something created by google which allowed a background process to monitor folders.

regards

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge I do not think its possible from the browser because of security concerns.  You'll need to rely on client software. You could provide your Java app as a software, similar to Dropbox.